# Factory class supporting JSF ManagedBean class

Tags: java, jsf, connection-pooling

I have a a JSF web application and an example Managed Bean called User:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User {

private String name, surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        updateName(name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    private void updateName(String name){
        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        //Update name via Connection
    }
}
```

Then I have an Example class ConnectionFactory.

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private static Queue<Connection> connections;

    static {
        //initialize connections
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
          return connections.poll();
    }

    //Other methods related to connection pooling, this is really just an example class

}
```

My question is, can such a factory class be used to provide DATABASE CONNECTIONS ? Is it guaranteed that every bean with any scope (from request to application scope) will share this one class during container runtime ?

I only want to lease connection to bean for the duration time of update methods. I dislike the idea of session scoped managed bean with long lifetime (sessions can take really long time) having class property injected with Connection objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you properly implement a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) then yes - the same object will be used by all beans (in the scope of the same JVM).

However I think you are reinventing the wheel and would suggest using a standard [connection pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjj.html). This way you can for example use your application server configuration tools to monitor and manage things like maximum number of open DB connections and such.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I am going to use existing pools, I just tried to simplify the question.